# pandas output timestamps to_excel with microseconds

Tags: excel, pandas, timestamp

I have microsecond resolution in my df which is very important but no matter what I try, I can't get excel to show microsecond resolution with either .xls or .xlsx.  Any ideas on how to get them to display without converting to a string explicitly?

Comment: Can you give an example showing this? Pandas' Timestamp is in nanoseconds, so microseconds are no problem

Comment: @AndyHayden actually, pandas does support it however no matter what you do Excel does not support microsecond resolution.  Pretty annoying if you ask me.  What I'm doing now is converting all timestamps to text before outputting to excel - the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of Pandas on GitHub (and in the soon to be released 0.13.1) you can specify the  Excel date format in the `ExcelWriter()` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([datetime(2014, 2, 1, 12, 30, 5, 60000)])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("time.xlsx", date_format='hh:mm:ss.000')

df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1")

writer.close()
```

Which will display the microsecond times (or at least milliseconds since that is Excel's display limit):

[image]

See also [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html).

Comment: Thanks, I installed 0.13.1 and I believe it is at least serializing microseconds but it's just too bad excel can't display microsecond resolution... Perhaps libreoffice does.